# Need suggestion to use SDL Translation product for automated translation work

Tags: translation-manager, worldserver

I am not sure if this is a right place to discuss this type of issue, but sharing for experts suggestion. My client needs an automated system for translation which translate the data with minimal manual intervention. Flow of data is high and they need translated data at run time(as fast as possible). This is a non-tridion based website and translation of data required is back and forth(example, Finnish to Swedish and Swedish to Finnish).
I am exploring all SDL language product but not able to find any product which can fulfill the requirement. I am already in touch with SDL marketing team to suggest some solution. Can anyone provide some suggestion if already worked on this kind of solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, your question might get flagged as off topic here.

If fast, "run time" translation is required then you will clearly not be able to rely on human translation due to the time that takes but instead will require some form of machine translation.

[SDL Language Cloud](http://www.sdl.com/languagecloud/) has a machine translation API available that you could use (this is the technology that powers SDL's own [FreeTranslation.com](http://www.freetranslation.com/), which does have support for Finnish and Swedish). There's also the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).

Comment: +1 for Language Cloud. Pretty easy to get started too, just create an account and get an API key.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as this is answering my question completely. Although I was expecting few more response to come up who have implemented fully automated translation system(Almost not exactly) by using a combination of products mentioned by David like for Translation Memory(World server) and for automated machine translation Google API.